# Is there a way by which I can select particular columns from an excel sheet based on the column number?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with thousands of  columns, and I want to select some of them, each has a column number, is there way by which I can select columns that meet the specific condition? e.g column with numbers 50, 70, 120, 154, 200. how to select them from an excel file with 2000 columns? is there any macros can do that?
thanks

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. Do you mean you want the 50th, 70th, 120th etc. column? Or columns that contain 50, 70, 120 etc? Also, do you want to select them or do something with them? Do you have any VBA you've attempted so far?

Comment: thanks@CLR . yes i mean the 50th, 70th, 120th. I neede just to select them. for the VBA I was used this macro                                            Sub Macro()
Range("a1,b1,d1,e1,g1,h1").EntireColumn.Select  
        End Sub                                                                                                          but this only valid if the headers of the columns are letters.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Wujaskun's answer and building upon it - you could do the following which would allow you to specify the column numbers in just one line and remove the need for repetitive coding:

```
Sub select_columns()

Dim myColumns As Range

myColumnNumbers = Array(1, 5, 9, 13, 17) '.. and on and on..

ReDim myColumn(UBound(myColumnNumbers)) As Range

For Each c In myColumnNumbers

    If myColumns Is Nothing Then
        Set myColumns = Columns(c).EntireColumn
    Else
        Set myColumns = Union(myColumns, Columns(c).EntireColumn)
    End If

Next

myColumns.Select

Set myColumns = Nothing

End Sub
```

One slight warning, don't repeat column numbers (or the first one at least) as this will cause the Union to reset.

**EDIT** - I've now improved the code to allow (or at least not cause issue) if the first column number is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union` to select multiple columns. I have created a short macro just to give you an idea how it works.

```
Sub select_columns()

Dim myColumns, myColumn(1 To 5) As Range

Set myColumn(1) = Columns(1).EntireColumn
Set myColumn(2) = Columns(3).EntireColumn
Set myColumn(3) = Columns(5).EntireColumn
Set myColumn(4) = Columns(7).EntireColumn
Set myColumn(5) = Columns(9).EntireColumn

Set myColumns = Union(myColumn(1), myColumn(2), myColumn(3), myColumn(4), myColumn(5))

myColumns.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Wujaszkun. This quite good if i want to select small number of columns but if i want to select let's 50 columns, the code will be quite long.

Comment: @Data Miner - It was just a sample code, in a final version you'll probably want to make it more flexible and use some kind of loop to add the columns to the `Union`, like CLR did in his answer.